# React Native websockets with hooks INVALID_STATE_ERR

Tags: react-native, websocket

React Native wont send multiple messages on state change throught websocket. Server recives 1st string normally and client gets console logs on every state change. Any idea why I get an error about state?

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.onopen = function (e) {
      socket.send(String(state?.x));

    };
    socket.send("test")  <-- this one does not work 
    console.log("send")
    socket.onmessage = function () {
      console.log("message")
    }

    socket.close();
  }, [state])
```

Returns error INVALID_STATE_ERR

Comment: are you using socket.io?

Comment: No I am not. React native supports websocket. I was thinking about using socket.io but I had problems setting it up.

Comment: [check this link](https://medium.com/@meshmmanuel/how-i-fixed-reactnative-websocket-invalid-state-err-fa065f49aa65) it may helps you.

Answer (score -1):

So basically when using react native with EXPO you will get those errors. After the application is build and installed (on the same phone) the application works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30594161)